# Error ACCESS on database 'neo4j' is not allowed for user on se of neo4j/graphql

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-graphql-js

I am using this in Apollo GraphQL server:

```
const { Neo4jGraphQL } = require('@neo4j/graphql');
```

And I am getting this error:  `Error  ACCESS on database 'neo4j' is not allowed for user myuser`

But I am not referring to the `neo4j` database.  I have specified a different DB to the driver: "mydb_name"

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password), {
        database: 'mydb_name', // Specify your database name here
    })
```

I set the the Home DB of that user to "mydb_name".

Why is th error referring to the `neo4j` DB? How to solve this?

If using directly with driver session query that working... But the  same with schema then getting error

Comment: I edited your question for clarity, but could not understand your last sentence, so left is as-is (did you mean that you did NOT get the error?). Please correct it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `database` config parameter [does not seem to be documented](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/lib6/types.js%7EConfig.html).

Try following the [documented approach to specifying the database](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql/current/driver-configuration/#_specifying_the_neo4j_database). That is, specify the database name the server should use when creating driver sessions:

```
await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    context: async ({ req }) => ({ req, sessionConfig: { database: "mydb_name" }}),
});
```